# Some functions/commands appear to be missing

Tags: functions, variables

I cannot call `emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column` mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Documentation-Tips.html) or `url-link` mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Common-Keywords.html). Neither using `M-x` nor in code. I use Emacs 28.2. Are these commands provided by a package ? As far as I read, these functions seem to be built in to Emacs. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column` is a variable, not a function. You can set it to a value, but you can't 'call' it.

Similarly, in the linked manual, `url-link` is not a function, but part of a value that is used in defining a customization item. It's not a function that can be called.

Comment: Thank you @Tyler. This line of code `:link '(url-link :tag "Homepage" "https://github.com/ymarco/auto-activating-snippets")` from [auto-activating-snippets](https://github.com/ymarco/auto-activating-snippets/tree/master) was hard to understand. Your answer and the documentation about `:tag` made it clear.

Comment: That single-quote character before the list tells you that the following list is literal data, not a function call. The quote character is itself "syntactic sugar" for the special form `quote`. The form `(quote (url-link :tag [...]))` is exactly equivalent to `'(url-link :tag [...])`.